# Не работает UPDATE с WHERE через PHP mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день!

```
$query = "UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_title` = '".$r['new_title']."' WHERE `ID` = '".$r['ID']."'";
$sqlres = mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

Что дает строку:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_title` = 'Example Post Title' WHERE `ID` = '2'
```

Прекрасно работает через тот же PhpMyadmin.
Также пробовал **mysqli_real_query** вместо **mysqli_query**. 
Все переменные работают и содержатся в запросе, проверяю через дебаггер.

Связь с базой данных есть, коннект установлен, ошибок нет.

```
mysqli_error($link);
```

Пустой. 
Делаю запросы SELECT и получаю результаты, а здесь затыка и уже перечитал все - у всех  работает такой код, нигде не найду в чем может быть проблема!

Также когда скрипт висит в дебаге и есть связь с БД, такой запрос не получается через тот же PHPMYADMIN отправить, phpmyadmin подвисает и пишет ошибку.

```
#1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Если скрипт остановить, то все ок.

Также пробовал варианты:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_title` = 'Example Post Title' WHERE `ID` = '2'
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_title` = 'Example Post Title' WHERE `ID` = '2';
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_title` = 'Example Post Title' WHERE `ID` = 2
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_title` = 'Example Post Title' WHERE `ID` = 2;
```

Вариант который предлагает сам PHPMYADMIN c указанием базы и колонки в таблице:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE `dbname`.`wp_posts` SET  `post_title` =  'Example Title' WHERE  `wp_posts`.`ID` =2;";

UPDATE `mh_parse`.`wp_posts` SET  `post_title` =  'Example Title' WHERE  `wp_posts`.`ID` =2;
```

Все равно ничего не срабатывает!

Comment: После `update` сделайте из скрипта `select` и посмотрите, изменилась ли строка. Судя по lock wait timeout - у вас открыта транзакция, но вы эту транзакцию так и не фиксируете впоследствии. Тогда при завершении скрипта транзакция откатывается и все изменения отменяются, а во время работы - другие пишущие запросы к этой строке будут ждать получения блокировки. Вполне согласуется с наблюдаемым поведением.

Comment: Я разобрался уже, оказалось что дело в том что при коннекте к базе у меня стояла опция mysqli_options($link, MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0')